# I am struggling grpc php extension installation on my ubuntu 20.04 server by using whm terminal

Tags: php, ubuntu, google-cloud-firestore, grpc, pear

I am using https://github.com/grpc/grpc repo to install grpc. But after **make** when I fire the "**make install**" command then I get error [This is the error in the terminal I get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XXGZ.png)

I don't know how to use **cmake** and and **bazel** to install this.

Please help. I am stuck in this from 2 days.
Thank You!

Comment: Same, though mine stops (or hang) in the middle of `make` command

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: screenshots of errors make it very hard for others to find answers to this specific problem.